# Inconsistent Array.includes() behaviour - identical arrays returning different results

Tags: javascript, arrays

Can anyone help explain this weird behaviour of Array.includes()?

I've updated the information provided to show how the arrays are built.
I'm using the spread operator as well as filtering, which as far as I'm aware both create new copies. I'm doing so as I believed that for state you should always create new copies of the objects in order to not mutate. I thought that's what you do with state.

[Screenshot from chrome console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1vyw.png)

---

To show how the arrays are built:

```
const PricingSection = ({
}) => {

  const [businessState, setBusinessState] = useState({
    purchase: {
      service: [],
      cost: []
    },
    subscription: {
      service: [],
      cost: []
    }
  });

  const [businessTotal, setBusinessTotal] = useState({
    purchase: [],
    subscription: []
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const sumSubscriptionBusiness = businessState.subscription.cost.reduce(
      (total, next) => total + Number(next),
      0
    );
    const sumPurchaseBusiness = businessState.purchase.cost.reduce(
      (total, next) => total + Number(next),
      0
    );
    setBusinessTotal({
      purchase: sumPurchaseBusiness,
      subscription: sumSubscriptionBusiness
    });
  }, [businessState]);



  const [toggleValue, toggleHandler] = useToggle(isChecked);

  const handleChecking = (e, item) => {
    const { name } = e.target;
    const { id } = e.target;
    const newService = item.service;
    const newCost = item.cost;
    const newPCost = item.pcost;

    if (
      name === "business" &&
      businessState.subscription.service[0] !== undefined &&
      !businessState.subscription.service.includes(newService) &&
      !businessState.purchase.service.includes(newService)
    ) {

      const oldBusinessPurchaseService = businessState.purchase.service;
      const oldBusinessPurchaseCost = businessState.purchase.cost;
      const oldBusinessSubscriptionService = businessState.subscription.service;
      const oldBusinessSubscriptionCost = businessState.subscription.cost;
      setBusinessState({
        purchase: {
          service: [...oldBusinessPurchaseService, item.service],
          cost: [...oldBusinessPurchaseCost, newPCost]
        },
        subscription: {
          service: [...oldBusinessSubscriptionService, item.service],
          cost: [...oldBusinessSubscriptionCost, newCost]
        }
      });
    }
    if (
      name === "business" &&
      businessState.subscription.service[0] !== undefined &&
      businessState.subscription.service.includes(newService) |
        businessState.purchase.service.includes(newService)
    ) {
      const removeBusinessIndex = businessState.subscription.service.indexOf(
        newService
      );
      const reducedBusinessSubscriptionService = businessState.subscription.service.filter(
        (s, i) => i !== removeBusinessIndex
      );

      const reducedBusinessSubscriptionCost = businessState.subscription.cost.filter(
        (s, i) => i !== removeBusinessIndex
      );

      const reducedBusinessPurchaseService = businessState.purchase.service.filter(
        (s, i) => i !== removeBusinessIndex
      );

      const reducedBusinessPurchaseCost = businessState.purchase.cost.filter(
        (s, i) => i !== removeBusinessIndex
      );

      setBusinessState({
        purchase: {
          service: [...reducedBusinessPurchaseService],
          cost: [...reducedBusinessPurchaseCost]
        },
        subscription: {
          service: [...reducedBusinessSubscriptionService],
          cost: [...reducedBusinessSubscriptionCost]
        }
      });
    }
    if (
      name === "business" &&
      businessState.subscription.service[0] === undefined
    ) {
      setBusinessState({
        purchase: {
          service: [newService],
          cost: [newPCost]
        },
        subscription: {
          service: [newService],
          cost: [newCost]
        }
      });
    }

  };

  const data = state.data;
  const activeStatus = state.active;

  return (

                    <PricingList>
                      {pricingTable.listItems.map((item, index) => (
                        <ListItem key={`pricing-table-list-${index}`}>
                          <Checkbox
                            name={`${pricingTable.category}`}
                            id={`${pricingTable.type}`}
                            labelText={item.service}
                            checked={toggleValue}
                            value={item}
                            onChange={e => {
                              toggleHandler;
                              handleChecking(e, item);
                            }}

                          />

                        </ListItem>
                      ))}
                    </PricingList>
  );
};

export default PricingSection;
```

The data comes from here:

```
export const YEARLY_PRICING_TABLE = [
{
    name: "Business Website",
    category: "business",
    type: "purchase",
    description: "For Small teams or group who need to build website ",
    price: "$6.00",
    priceLabel: "Per month & subscription yearly",
    buttonLabel: "Register Now",
    url: "#",
    trialButtonLabel: "Or Start 14 Days trail",
    trialURL: "#",
    listItems: [
      {
        service: ["Mobile-ready, Responsive Design"],
        cost: [6],
        pcost: [600]
      },
      {
        service: ["Blog Articles"],
        cost: [14],
        pcost: [1300]
      },
      {
        service: ["Collect visitor information (email / phone)"],
        cost: [10],
        pcost: [1000]
      },
      {
        service: ["eCommerce Store "],
        cost: [25],
        pcost: [3200]
      },
      {
        service: ["30+ Webmaster Tools"],
        cost: [2],
        pcost: [500]
      }
    ]
  },
...
],
export const MONTHLY_PRICING_TABLE = [
{
    name: "Business Website",
    category: "business",
    type: "subscription",
    description: "Multi-page Website for Small-Large Businesses",
    price: "$9.87",
    priceLabel: "Per month & subscription yearly",
    buttonLabel: "Register Now",
    url: "#",
    trialButtonLabel: "Or Start 14 Days trail",
    trialURL: "#",
    listItems: [
      {
        service: ["Mobile-ready, Responsive Design"],
        cost: [6],
        pcost: [600]
      },
      {
        service: ["Blog Articles"],
        cost: [14],
        pcost: [1300]
      },
      {
        service: ["Collect visitor information (email / phone)"],
        cost: [10],
        pcost: [1000]
      },
      {
        service: ["eCommerce Store "],
        cost: [25],
        pcost: [3200]
      },
      {
        service: ["30+ Webmaster Tools"],
        cost: [2],
        pcost: [500]
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

Comment: Can you post yout arrays as they are instead of the logged version of them? Right now it is really hard to understand their values

Comment: I would guess that you have appended temp2 to temp1 instead of building the array from scratch.  So temp1 actually does contain (a reference to) temp2, so temp1.includes(temp2) is true.  However I bet with temp3/temp4 you constructed the array a different way.  Please show how you build these arrays.

Comment: Comparing arrays and objects doesn't compare their contents, it requires them to be references to the same instance.

Comment: @CalvinNunes I've updated with the information :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The includes() method determines whether a typed array includes a
>   certain **element**, returning true or false as appropriate.

You can't compare arrays contents' against each other using `includes()` method you can use any other methods like loops. Read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

Comment: Thank you! I had a vague memory about the reference of the object being what was compared, but didn't know how to overcome that. A loop it is! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

2 things to keep in mind:

- Arrays are objects and
- Equality of objects is based on references being the same, not just values.

```js
let a = 3;
let b = 3;
console.log(a === b); // true

let aObj = {x: 3};
let bObj = {x: 3};
let cObj = aObj;
console.log(aObj === bObj); // false
console.log(aObj === cObj); // true
```

Comment: Thank you @junvar, that explains my confusion! As rogue-scarlet explained, I can use loops instead :)